How to Resolve HttpRequest AssertionError in Django Friend Request View?
I'm working on a Django project where users can send and accept friend requests. When a friend request is accepted, I want to add the sender and receiver to each other's friend list and send a notification. However, I'm encountering an error when trying to send the notification.
Problem Description:
When a user accepts a friend request, I want to add the sender to the receiver's friends list and vice versa. However, I get the following error:
AssertionError: The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `userauths.models.User`.
[28/May/2024 16:09:33] "GET /accept-friend-request/?id=8 HTTP/1.1" 500 121207

so let me provide the link api to the function:
path("accept-friend-request/", views.accept_friend_request, name="accept-friend-request"),

let me provide the accept_friend_request function
@api_view(['GET'])
@login_required
def accept_friend_request(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        sender_id = request.GET.get('id')
        receiver = request.user

        # Log the sender_id
        logger.debug(f"Sender ID: {sender_id}")

        try:
            # Retrieve the sender user from the database
            sender = User.objects.get(id=sender_id)

            # Retrieve the sender's profile
            sender_profile = sender.profile

            # Add sender's profile to receiver's friends and vice versa
            receiver.profile.friends.add(sender_profile)
            sender_profile.friends.add(receiver.profile)

            # Delete the friend request
            friend_request = FriendRequest.objects.filter(receiver=receiver, sender=sender).first()
            friend_request.delete()

            # Send notification
            send_notification(sender, receiver, None, None, noti_friend_request_accepted)

            data = {
                "message": "Accepted",
                "bool": True,
            }
            return JsonResponse({'data': data})
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            logger.error(f"User with ID {sender_id} does not exist.")
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'User does not exist.'}, status=404)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Only GET requests are allowed.'})

Question:
How can I resolve the AssertionError related to HttpRequest in this context?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
What I Tried:
Logging: I added logging to ensure that the sender_id is being retrieved correctly, which it is.
Profile Retrieval: I confirmed that the sender.profile and receiver.profile are being accessed correctly.
Database Check: I confirmed that both the user and the friend request exist in the database.
Expected Behavior:
I expect the friend request to be accepted, the users to be added to each other's friend list, and a notification to be sent without causing an AssertionError.

Please [edit] your question and add a [mre]. Also add the complete error traceback.

This platform has made rules that make it less helpful. If you understand my question, why not help?

We can't reproduce your problem with the code you've shared with us. My comment is very much helping you by pointing you to resources that will help you create reproducible code.

I think this function is fine, the problem most likely lies in the send_notification one.
You call it this way :
send_notification(sender, receiver, None, None, noti_friend_request_accepted)

If the send_notification is a view, it expects implicitly a HttpRequest object as first argument, while you provide a user object :
sender = User.objects.get(id=sender_id)

Still assuming that send_notification is a view, you should actually extract the logic that sends the notification from it and call it inside your accept_friend_request view, because calling another view will not work the way you expect it.
